# True/False: If $v$ is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from DFS(s), then $v$ is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from BFS(s)

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Let G = (V,E) be a connected undirected graph. Let s in V be a vertex in the graph.

True/False: If v is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from DFS(s), then v is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from BFS(s) (v != s).

I assume that this one is True, and I think that because if v is a leaf in every DFS(s), that means v has no children on G graph, but I struggle to prove it.

I'd like to get some help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The contrapositive of that proposition, which is equivalent in classical logic, is True/False if there exists a BFS tree from s in which v is not a leaf, then there exists a DFS tree from s in which v is not a leaf. Is that easier for you to prove?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Indeed the contrapositive way sounds easier. So my first statement here should be "Choose a spanning tree results from BFS(s) in which v is not a leaf" - and start working from here? If not, I'd appreciate a head start :) Thanks!

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I think I got it. Assume there exists a spanning tree resulting from BFS(s) such that $v$ is not a leaf. Then $v$ has at least 2 neighbors in the spanning tree, $v_1,v_2$. So $(v,v_1),(v,v_2) \in T_{BFS}$ which means $(v,v_1),(v,v_2) \in G$, so by definition of DFS, there exists a spanning tree in which $(v,v_1),(v,v_2) \in T_{DFS}$. Is that correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: @CalculusLover you're on the right track, but you should justify the last step (degree ≥2 implies exists DFS tree) in more detail.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat What do you mean by that?